Can't one always define potential energy $U=-m\ddot xx$?
Can't one always define potential energy $$U=-m\ddot xx$$ so that $$F=m\ddot x=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}?$$
An example is gravitational potential energy $U=mgh$ where $h=x$ and $g=-\ddot x$. I know this has to be wrong somehow because not all force fields are conservative, but I can't see it.

Something else to note is that if you want a conservative force law, you would want an equation of the form $$ m\ddot{x} = \text{something else as a function of position}, $$ In your case, you get $m\ddot{x} = m\ddot{x}$, which gives no information about the force law that the mass is subjected to. In fact, the equation of motion, if you can call it that, reduces to $0 = 0$.

How does $U=-m\ddot xx$ lead to $F=m\ddot x=-\partial U/\partial x$? Also, $g=-\ddot x$ seems to be an expression that only holds in very particular situations and not in general.

@Steeven Integrate $m\ddot x$ with respect to $x$ assuming $m$ and $\ddot x$ are independent of $x$


In a nutshell, the Newton's 2nd law$^{1}$
$$m{\bf a}~\approx~{\bf F}\tag{1}$$ ("EOM") equates kinematics ("mass times acceleration") with dynamics ("forces").

The (generalized) potential energy $U$ [if it exists] satisfies by definition that the force
$$\begin{align}-{\bf F}~=~\frac{\delta U}{\delta{\bf r}}~\equiv~&\frac{\partial U}{\partial{\bf r}}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial U}{\partial{\bf v}}+\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^2\frac{\partial U}{\partial{\bf a}}\cr
&-\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)^3\frac{\partial U}{\partial{\bf j}}+\ldots\end{align}\tag{2}$$
is minus the (functional) derivative of $U$.

The (generalized) potential energy $U({\bf r},{\bf v},{\bf a},{\bf j},\ldots,t)$ may in principle depend on velocity, acceleration, jerk, etc. [Think e.g. on the Abraham-Lorentz force.]

The potential energy $U$ should always be associated [via eq. (2)] with the dynamics ("forces"); not the kinematics ("mass times acceleration"). This is where OP's suggestion$^2$ fails: At best it produces a useless trivial identity rather than a useful non-trivial EOM
$$m{\bf a}~\approx~-\frac{\delta U}{\delta{\bf r}}.\tag{3}$$
Kinematics and dynamics should not be conflated.

See also e.g. this related Phys.SE post.



$^1$ The $\approx$ symbol means equality modulo eqs. of motion (EOM).
$^2$ It might be helpful to point out that if "mass times acceleration" $m{\bf a}$ is interpreted as a force, its corresponding (generalized) potential energy (2) is not surprisingly the kinetic energy $\frac{m}{2}{\bf v}^2$ (modulo total time derivative terms). Which can be rewritten to e.g. $\frac{m}{2}{\bf v}^2-\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{m}{2}{\bf r}\cdot{\bf v})=-\frac{m}{2}{\bf r}\cdot{\bf a}$ (modulo total time derivative terms). The latter is a half times OP's proposal.

I get that the trivial identity might be useless, but I want to know why it is (or should be) false? If it is not false, then all force fields have a potential energy function. So far, only @Refik Mansuroglu gave a convincing answer. What do you think?

I updated the answer.

I know it's quite late but I am not sure I understand why such a generalised potential energy function may not exist. It seems to me that it should be possible to express a force as such; to justify energy conservation for example. Also, what does modulo mean?

I updated the answer.

Answers from the comments, as suggested here. Answers should be posted as answers, and comments should be used for their intended purpose.
@Refik Mansuroglu

You are assuming that $\partial\ddot x/\partial x=0$, which you cannot always do.


@Ján Lalinský

You can define such function $U(x,\ddot x)$, but it won't be recognized as potential energy, because the important defining feature of a potential energy function is that it depends only on coordinates, not velocities or higher derivatives.


@Maximal Ideal

Something else to note is that if you want a conservative force law, you would want an equation of the form $$m\ddot x=\text{something else as a function of position}$$ In your case, you get $m\ddot x=m\ddot x$ which gives no information about the force law that the mass is subjected to. In fact, the equation of motion, if you can call it that, reduces to $0=0$.


In the expression $U(x)$, $x$ is meant to be a coordinate describing space. You can evaluate the function $U$ at any spatial point $x$. This is important since it means that the force $F$ is defined everywhere.
Meanwhile, in an expression like $x(t)$, $\dot{x}(t)$, or $\ddot{x}(t)$, $x$ is meant to be understood as a trajectory of a particle. In particular, a time derivative like $\dot{x}$ makes sense if you think of the velocity of a moving particle following a path $x(t)$. But, if you want to think of $x$ as simply a coordinate -- a label for a fixed point in space -- then the time derivative of that label doesn't really mean much. So a function like $f(\ddot{x}(t))$ best understood as a function of a particular trajectory. You need more information than the labels of individual points in space, you also need to know how that particle moves in time, to evaluate $f$.
To say this differently, recall that Newton's laws are really a second order differential equation. We are meant to solve it to determine $x(t)$. In an expression like $m\ddot{x}=-\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$, the right hand side is a function of $x$, so we have a well-defined differential equation. If we used $U=m \ddot{x} x$, then we no longer have a differential equation to solve, but simply a definition of $U$. The equation becomes a tautology. We need to set $m\ddot{x}$ equal to something independent in order to have a differential equation to solve.

Don't we define $U=mgh$ for example? $g$ here is just $-\ddot x$ while $h=x$.

Right so $g$ in $U=mgh$ is a constant. So the differential equation you're solving reads $m\ddot{x}=-mg$. You can then cancel the $m$'s and get $\ddot{x}=-g$. This is an equation you can solve, and then get $x(t)=x_0 + v_0 t - \frac{1}{2} gt^2$, where $x_0$ and $v_0$ are initial conditions (integration constants) you get solving the equation. Now, it's true, that the acceleration equals $-g$, but that is new information, and you can use that information to solve the equation. If you had written $\ddot{x}=\ddot{x}$, you would have a true statement, but no external information (...)

(...) you could use to solve the equation. In $U(x)=mgx$ you can evaluate $U$ at any spatial point you want, without needing to know the trajectory of the particle.


Can't one always define $U=-m\ddot xx$?

One can make such a definition, but one should not do so. A function $U$ defined as $-m\ddot x x$ would not be the correct potential energy for any case beside a one-dimensional constant force.
The potential energy is usually defined for a conservative force, up to a constant, via
$$
\vec F = -\nabla U\;,
$$
If you choose to make some other ad hoc definition like
$$
U = -m\ddot x x
$$
then no one will understand what you are talking about, since we already have a well-defined definition of potential energy (up to a constant).

Consider, for example, a Hooke's law spring force. The usual meanings of force and potential energy are well known:
$$
F = -kx
$$
$$
U = \frac{1}{2}kx^2\;.
$$
If you try to use your flawed definition, you wind up with
$$
U_{your\;proposal} = kx^2\;,
$$
which is clearly wrong by a factor of 2.

This stems from the fact that I implicitly assumed $\frac{\partial\ddot x}{\partial x}=0$ like one of the comments say. Thank you for providing an example. In addition, you are right in regards to the definition being ad hoc and useless because Newton's law is helpful in the first place because it equates dynamics with kinematics like @Qmechanic said.

Instead of the dot notation for time derivatives I will use the trio
$s$ position
$v$ velocity
$a$ acceleration
And of course $t$ for time
By definiton:
$$ v = \frac{ds}{dt} \ \Leftrightarrow \ ds = v \ dt  \tag{1}  $$
$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt} \ \Leftrightarrow \ dv = a \ dt  \tag{2}  $$

Next: evaluate the integral of acceleration with respect to position coordinate, $\int_{s_0}^s \ a \ ds$
$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds \tag{3}  $$
$$ \int_{t_0}^t a \ v \ dt \tag{4} $$
$$ \int_{t_0}^t v \ a \ dt  \tag{5} $$
$$ \int_{v_0}^v v \ dv  \tag{6} $$
First (1) was used to change the differential from $ds$ to $dt$, with corresponding change of limits. Next (2) was used - with change of limits - to arrive at (6).
(6) evaluates to $\tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2$, so we have the following mathematical relation:
$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2  \tag{7} $$
This is a general theorem; the definitions (1) and (2) are sufficient.
Multiplying both sides with $m$ for mass turns (7) into a dynamics statement:
$$ \int_{s_0}^s ma \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2 \tag{8} $$
And of course: if $F=ma$ holds good we can substitute $ma$ with $F$:
$$ \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2 \tag{9} $$

(9) informs us:
If a force field has the property that its corresponding potential is a function of the position coordinate only then:
$$ ma = \frac{dU}{dx} \tag{10} $$
